# Find out who is using a shared mount?

Tags: mount, nfs

We have a mount point shared by many Linux hosts. We need to figure out which accounts are reading/writing files using which accounts and at what time. How should we go about this?

Answer (score 4):

If you have `nfswatch` installed you can use it to determine the hosts that are accessing the NFS server. You'll need to use the `-clients` switch.

#### Example

```
$ sudo nfswatch -clients
mulder.mydom.net            Mon Oct 13 16:28:55 2014   Elapsed time:   00:01:00
Interval packets:   337 (network)        154 (to host)          0 (dropped)
Total packets:         1308 (network)        316 (to host)          0 (dropped)
                     Monitoring packets from interface vmbr0
                     int   pct    total                      int   pct    total
NFS3 Read             64   42%      162 TCP Packets          151   98%      293
NFS3 Write             0    0%        0 UDP Packets            2    1%       13
NFS Read               0    0%        0 ICMP Packets           0    0%        0
NFS Write              0    0%        0 Routing Control        0    0%        0
NFS Mount              0    0%        0 Addr Resolution        0    0%        3
Port Mapper            4    3%        4 Rev Addr Resol         0    0%        0
RPC Authorization      0    0%        0 Ether/FDDI Bdcst       2    1%       15
Other RPC Packets      1    1%        1 Other Packets          1    1%        7
                                 2 client hosts
Client host          int   pct    total Client host          int   pct    total
byers                  1    2%       13 skinner               63   98%      149
```

In the above output there are 2 hosts that are actively using the NFS server, `byers` and `skinner`. You can see the list of clients in the lower part of the output.

You can also use `netstat -an | grep :2049` to see which hosts are connecting to the NFS server as well.

I would use `nfswatch` since it can continuously log to a file that can then be reviewed lattter.

Answer (score 0):

There is an nfs command that you can see which hosts have mounted the NFS filesystem from the server system (BTW, not always totally accurate).

However, tracking that back down into a specific user account would have to be done at each individual host running something like lsof.